# Trying to find an old Iron Man comic where he's attacked by energy-draining "polka dots"

Tags: marvel, comics, iron-man

**Plot Summary/Details**

Whichever supervillain Iron Man was fighting in this particular issue (it *may* have been Midas and/or Madame Masque, but I'm not certain of that), at one point he is attacked by a whirling swarm of brightly colored disks, looking very much like polka dots.  IIRC, the disks attach themselves to his armor, and begin draining energy from him.  I believe the background in the story panels is all white, presumably to highlight the colored disks.  Iron Man is able to thwart the devices by (again, IIRC) reversing the polarity of his armor or something like that.  The disks are repulsed and possibly destroyed.  In any case, ol' Shellhead lives to see another day.

**Timeframe/Publication Details**

This issue would have been published no later than 1980 or so, and probably in the late 1970s. That's all I can really recall here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is [The Invincible Iron Man #101](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Iron_Man_Vol_1_101) story *The Monster of Frankenstein* from 1977.

One of the weapons deployed is energy-discs. Tony attempts to reverse the polarity of his suit but fails.

[image: Panel 1: A speech box says "Oh, that you shall, intruder -- to your everlasting regret!" Iron Man is seen flinching as blue energy surrounds him, with a ZAM! at the bottom of the panel. Panel 2: Iron Man is seen kneeling, while blue energy circles him. He is thinking "Being... bombarded... with ionic force!" Panel 3: Iron Man is now standing up as blue and white discs cascading around him, thinking "Another attack! Metallic energy-discs adhering to me! Ordinarily I could draw power from them--" Panel 4: Iron Man staggers under the discs, thinking "--but the ionic force is keeping me from reversing my polarity!" Panel 5: Iron Man thinks "Armor... building to an overload! Can't keep it from--" as he is shown in silhouette against blue energy, with yellow electricity arcing over his suit. The bottom of the panel says VZZZZZZ. Panel 6: The infopanel says "It is over!" as Iron Man falls to the ground, smoke rising from his suit, in front of several people.]

Comment: That is the issue, no question.  I can remember the cover of the issue as clear as day now.

Comment: In addition to the Marvel Comics universe and a fantasy universe populated by dwarves, we clearly have some crossover here from the Star Trek universe, as evidenced by the Captain Kirk monologue and the high density of pseudoscientific gibberish.

Answer (score 8):

This might be *[Tales of Suspense Vol 1 #59](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Tales_of_Suspense_Vol_1_59)* (1964). A villain named [Black Knight](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Nathan_Garrett_(Earth-616)) fires a bunch of power draining discs which attach themselves to Iron Man's armour, although he manages to shake them off by spiraling downwards at high speed.

[image: Panel 1: With the caption "And below, oblivious to the raging battle...", a red-haired woman leans out of a window, saying "Happy! Don't look down!", as a man in a green suit stands on a ledge on the side of the building, saying "Who's lookin' anywhere?? My eyes are closed!!" Panel 2: In the background, Happy says "I can't stand to think of the boss, maybe unconscious in his office, with no one there to help...!" In the foreground, Black Knight says "Ahhh! What have we there?!" Panel 3: Black Knight says "Just what I need - a hostage! So I'll just insert my little automatic lasso into my lance's accessory chamber..." Panel 4: A speech box says "Then, presto! I've caught my human fish!" as Happy is shown being dragged off of the building with a rope, saying "Wha--??" Panel 5: Iron Man, flying towards Black Knight (who is on a winged horse and dragging Happy in the lasso) says "Don't struggle, Happy -- you might weaken the knot which is holding you! I'll free you somehow!" Black Knight responds "A laudable ambition, Iron Man -- but one you will never achieve!" Panel 6: Black Knight says "And now, while you wonder what to do next, how about sampling some of my special little "doughnuts"! You might find them rather amusing!" Several green electronic-looking circles are seen shooting towards Iron Man. Black Knight continues "Each one contains a small electronic power drainer -- as you shall see!"]

[image: Panel 7: In a blue sky, Iron Man tries to dodge the green circles, thinking "They're hitting me! Clinging to my armor! I can't hurl them back at the Black Knight -- I might hit poor Happy!" Panel 8: Iron Man's suit is covered with the green discs, as he thinks "I can feel the discs starting to drain away my transistor power now! There's just one desperate gamble left for me to make..." Panel 9: Iron Man is seen spiraling down to the ground, thinking "If I dive down fast enough, it may affect their mechanisms to make them useless against me! here goes!" Black Knight sees him going down and says "I've beaten him! He's plunging to the ground!" Panel 10: Happy looks up in horror as Black Knight says "Now, I no longer need you! So you may join your iron-clad friend..." Panel 11: Black Knight continues "And so farewell, fool!" Happy is seen falling head-first, a large building visible on the ground below. Panel 12: Iron Man flies through the air holding Happy, saying "Well, my little stunt was double effective! Not only did I shake the Black Knight's discs off me... ...but I also tricked him into releasing you so that I could catch you!" Happy responds "Whew! You can play on my ball team any time, pal!"]

Comment: Interesting that this has apparently happened twice.